# Accessing KO component fields in viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

I have created my first KO component :

components.js

```
ko.components.register('team-dropdown', {
    viewModel: function (params) {

        var self = this;
        self.teamNames = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.ajax({
                url: 'http://footballcomps.cloudapp.net/Teams',
                type: 'get',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data['value'], function (key, value) {
                        self.teamNames.push(value.TeamName);
                    });
                    console.dir(self.teamNames);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });

        self.selectedTeam = ko.observable();
    },
    template: { require: 'text!components/team-dropdown.html' }
});
```

team-dropdown.html

```
<div id="teams" class="inputBlock form-group">
<select class="form-control" name="teamName" data-bind="options: teamNames, value:selectedTeam"></select>
<label id="lblHomeTeam" data-bind="text: selectedTeam"></label>
```

And here is my view where I want to use the component :

```
<div class="row" id="divFixture">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Add new fixture</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <form data-bind="submit: fixture.addFixture">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <team-dropdown />
                </div>....
            </form>
```

And my stripped down view model :

```
define(['knockout', 'knockout.validation', 'common', 'components'], function (ko) {

    return function fixtureViewModel() {

        function fixture(fixtureId, fixtureDate, homeId, homeName, homeBadge, homeScore, awayId, awayName, awayBadge, awayScore) {
            this.FixtureId = fixtureId;
            this.FixtureDate = fixtureDate;
            this.HomeId = homeId;
            this.HomeName = homeName;
            this.HomeBadge = homeBadge;
            this.HomeScore = homeScore;
            this.AwayId = awayId;
            this.AwayName = awayName;
            this.AwayBadge = awayBadge;
            this.AwayScore = awayScore;
        }

        var self = this;

        self.Id = ko.observable();
        self.FixtureDate = ko.observable();
        self.HomeId = ko.observable();
        self.HomeName = ko.observable();
        self.HomeBadge = ko.observable();
        self.HomeScore = ko.observable();
        self.AwayId = ko.observable();
        self.AwayName = ko.observable();
        self.AwayBadge = ko.observable();
        self.AwayScore = ko.observable();

        self.selectedTeam = ko.observable();

        self.addFixture = function() {

            //how do I reference the selected item from my component here?

    };     
});
```

How do I reference the item I have selected in my component in self.addFixture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `team-dropdown` is meant to be a reusable component, you should provide a way to bind to it. As you have it, it is a standalone control, the outside world cannot interact with it except through the observables you have defined which doesn't make it very flexible.

I would add parameters to it where you can set what observables to bind to the value.  Your fixtures has a `selectedTeam` property so that seems like a likely candidate.

```
ko.components.register('team-dropdown', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        var self = this,
            teamNames = ko.observableArray([]),
            // default to a local observable if value not provided
            selectedTeam = params.value || ko.observable();

        // you probably don't want others to directly modify the teamNames array
        self.teamNames = ko.pureComputed(teamNames);
        self.selectedTeam = selectedTeam;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://footballcomps.cloudapp.net/Teams',
            type: 'get',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data['value'], function (key, value) {
                    // push to the local `teamNames` array
                    teamNames.push(value.TeamName);
                });
                console.dir(teamNames);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    },
    template: { require: 'text!components/team-dropdown.html' }
});
```

Then set the parameter when you use the component:

```
<form data-bind="submit: fixture.addFixture">
    <div class="form-group">
        <team-dropdown params="value: fixture.selectedTeam" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The selected value should now be set in the `selectedTeam` of your fixture, so you can just use that.

```
self.addFixture = function() {
    var selectedTeam = self.selectedTeam(); // should have the value
};
```

Comment: But isn't the idea of components that you can plug them into a variety of view models?  What if I have for example a datepicker component and I want to use it in many different view models? That was the idea behind what I was trying to achieve here.

Comment: I might just have the wrong high-level picture in my head on what's used for what in your example.  What is the main view model? What is being "added" and to what?

Comment: I do not have one 'main' view model in the traditional KO sense, I will have several view models eg fixtureViewModel, teamViewModel etc. The fixtureViewModel is the one in the third code sample above, I will be using it to view/add/edit/delete fixtures, which will include team names, date, score etc.  The team component I am planning to use in both fixture and team view models and possibly other view models later. AddFixture will add a new fixture to a fixtures array which will be written to the backend db.

Comment: Ok, I think I have a better idea on how everything is interacting. The component `team-dropwdown` is meant to be used when composing other views.  In that case, you just need a general way to access/bind to the value.